# Get api from nested dynamic routing nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have a folder structure NEXT JS pages/api/product/[id]/index.js,
what's the URL to get Api index in the [id] folder?

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCg3i.png)

```
pages/
  api/
    product/
        [id]/
           index.js
```

I want to put the url here ([code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trIvo.png))

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/product/????/${product.parent}`);
```

I want get product.parent from [id]/index.js

Comment: not sure about the parent
`const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/product/${product.parent}`);` this will give you product response

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), and then accessing your query params inside the array provided.

file: /api/product/[...product].js

And then accessing the query params as array:

/api/product/productParent/anotherQuery

```
  const {product} = req.query
  const productParent = product[0]
  const anotherQuery = product[1]
```

Hope you get a more clear insight on how dynamic routing works.